# ¿Cómo puedo optimizar este código en python?

Tags: python, imagen, jerarquía

Llevo unos días pensando como optimizar la función generateHerarchy, la cual se encarga de, dada una lista de polígonos, reestructura la jerarquía para generar una estructura de polígonos y agujeros dentro de los mismos.

El problema es que el coste computacional de esta función es muy alto, de orden de n cuadrado. Me gustaría poder realizar una optimización para que consuma menos tiempo y menos memoria si fuera posible.

El código completo es el siguiente. Yo comienzo llamando a la función generateShapes, la cual la paso por parámetro una imagen binarizada. Esta imagen binarizada la trato de vectorizar para poder pasarlo a un shapefile.

```
# Obtención de contornos (sobre máscara)
def getContoursMask(imgData):
    kernel = np.asarray([[1, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 1]])
    api = ndimage.convolve(imgData.copy(), kernel)
    return measure.find_contours(api, 1, fully_connected='low',positive_orientation='high')


# Pasar los píxeles de una capa a coordenadas xy
def pix2xyGDAL(row, col, affine):
        #a, b, xoff, d, e, yoff, = affine
        xoff, a, b, yoff, d, e = affine
        x = float(col * a + row * b + xoff)
        y = float(col * d + row * e + yoff)
        return x, y
    

# Listado de polígonos, transformados de píxeles a coordenadas x, y
def getPolygons(contours, affine, marg):
    polis = [Polygon([pix2xyGDAL(x, y, affine) for x, y in elem]) 
             for elem in contours if np.shape(elem)[0] > marg
            ]
    return polis

# Reestructurar la geometria
def generateHerarchy(geometry):
    pols, holes = [], []
    for posi, grande in enumerate(geometry):
        ret = []
        for posj, p in enumerate(geometry):
            if ( posj != posi and p.within(grande)):
                ret.append(p); 
                holes.append(p)
        if grande not in holes:
            aux = Polygon(grande.exterior.coords, [r.exterior.coords for r in ret]) if len(ret) > 0 else Polygon(grande.exterior.coords)
            pols.append(aux)
    return pols

def createShapeFileContoursGDAL(contours, rt,  crs, dst, date):
    sc = {'geometry': 'Polygon','properties': {'id': 'int', 'date': 'str', 'area':'float'}}
    polis = generateHerarchy(getPolygons(contours, rt.GetGeoTransform(), 10))
    with fiona.open(dst, 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile',crs=from_epsg(crs), schema=sc) as c:  # creates new file to be written to
        {c.write({'geometry': mapping(polis[j]),'properties': {'id': j, 'date': date, 'area': polis[j].area},}) for j in range(len(polis))}


def generateShapes(img, rt, threshold, ops): 

    # Generamos las capas referentes
    SCAconts = getContoursMask(img)

    # Sacamos informacion del sistema de referencia
    proj = osr.SpatialReference(wkt=rt.GetProjection())

    # Almacenamos los contornos en un archivo shp
    dst_shp = join(ops['PathShapes'], ops['date'].replace(':','_'))
    makeFolder(dst_shp)
    dst_shp = join(dst_shp, f'sn_{int(threshold*10)}_.shp')
    createShapeFileContoursGDAL(SCAconts, rt, proj.GetAttrValue('AUTHORITY',1), dst_shp, ops['date'])
```

No se si podríais ayudarme :)

Un saludo

Comment: Por favor, publica un código que sea llegar y copiar en el IDE, para no tener que investigar que pueda ser `geometry` o de donde viene `Polygon`. Agrega un ejemplo de las entradas y salidas que produces actualmente, para validar la corrección de las respuestas

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Ahí lo tienes, muchas gracias :), el problema para comprobarlo es que uso un proceso sobre imágenes satelitales anteriormente, por lo que es complicado. No se si has trabajado alguna vez con la librería shapely

Comment: Que quiere decir optimizar? menos lineas? menos memoria? mas velocidad? las preguntas sobre optimizacion muchas veces no tienen una respuesta y llevan a discusiones extendidas...